# Where is the 'Tests Output Pane'?

Tags: visual-studio

> Unexpected error detected. Check the Tests Output Pane for details.

Where is the 'Tests Output Pane'? I can't find it anywhere in Visual Studio. I found 'Test *Explorer*' but it doesn't show any details.

Answer (score 258, accepted):

In the output window there is combobox "show output from". Choose Tests as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10159828/vs-11-beta-cannot-start-process-because-a-file-name-has-not-been-provided)

Comment: This is the correct answer. Selecting "Tests" from the combobox is the key.

Comment: When I do this I only get *One or more errors occurred.*

Comment: In the main menu of VS, choose View > Output, then within the Output pane, pick "Tests".

Answer (score 40):

The message really **should be** this

> Unexpected error detected. Check the `Output` window for details by toggling the `Show output from:` section to `Tests` drop down.

---

#### Why the Confusion?

For the `Tests` window is, *buried*, in the output window. That window acts as the main window that shows the textual `Build` information; and hides the test result info in another dropdown.

So in the `OutputWindow` select `Tests` after a run.

[image]

Comment: people like you should work at MS to make errors more usable. I had a funny one, "unable to copy a value because it's used by another process" and here MS again forgot to output the most important thing, the process name :)

Comment: @PawelCioch at the time of this writing I was still a MS MVP. Even though I am no longer one, I still report issues I run into w/Microsoft. So I've kinda worked for Microsoft.

Answer (score 27):

Go to the view tab at the top of your screen, and select output.

[image: VS view output]

Answer (score 6):

If you're looking for the actual issue, for me it was:

**vstest.discoveryengine.exe** and
**vstest.executionengine.exe**

Open up Task Manager, go to Processes tab, right-click and End Process. Restart Visual Studio.

Comment: I can't find these processes in Task Manager - where should I look?  Also, is killing the processes really the heart of the issue?

Comment: @Savage It was for me, but IIRC I got a horribly cryptic error like "One or more errors occured" and killing these processes fixed it.

Comment: Fixed it for me, but that's not to say it's the same issue. I never found out the actual cause...

Answer (score 3):

For me killing vstest.console.exe and vstest.discoveryengine.exe processes did the trick. No need to restart visual studio.

Comment: How does that _show_ the output from unittests and Console outputs?

Answer (score 1):

In case this helps anyone. All my test cases vanished from the Test Explorer (VS 2019 Pro v16.5.4) and I noticed the inconspicuous message in the status bar - `unexpected error detected. Check the Tests Output Pane for details`.

Restarting Visual Studio did not help. Restarting as administrator did not help too.

I followed @Ben-Power into Task Manager and found at least 5 occurrences of `vstest.console.exe` processes running.

Killed all and opened Visual Studio again. Test Explorer loaded all tests as expected.

Answer (score 1):

from the output section, a Combobox will appear and you will find there build, debug similarly tests too

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3sMYK.png)

Answer (score 0):

In case this helps anyone...  I had same problem with the TINY HIDDEN error message on the bar on the bottom of Visual Studio:
**Unexpected error detected. Check the Tests Output Pane for details.**

After the info in previous answers helped me find the Tests Output Pane...
The error message I found indicated that VS was trying to run "Release" version of tests, even though VS was set to select "Debug".  VS could not find the "Release" test assembly, because it had not been built!

I had been switching between "Release" and "Debug" previously. VS must have bug that does not handle switching properly all of the time.

**SOLULTION:  Restart Visual Studio.**
After restarting, Test Explorer picked up the "Debug" setting -- and used "Debug" version of the test assembly.

Answer (score 0):

So for me , I resolved it by just deleting the **root** folder on this path.

**C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Frameworks64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root**

Just delete this root folder & you should be good to go :)

Answer (score 0):

Change Terminal from show output from:
[image]