# NUnit tests not list in Test Explorer with Nunit Test Adapter is installed

Tags: visual-studio-2013, nunit

I am using vs 2013 pro.

I've installed NUnit and NUnit Test Adapter for VS2012, 2013, 2015.

I find there is no tests show up in Test Explorer. I rebuilt the solution, I restarted the computer, no help. I set platform targets for the main project and the test project to use any CPU, no help, set to x86, no help too.

Please help me. Thank you.

Comment: Which versions of NUnit, and the test adapter are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had similar problem after installed NUnit.3.2.1.msi and NUnit3 TestAdapter as extension in VisualStudio 2015. In case it helps you to see the tests at least in one way, here is what I did: Although there was no tests visible in Test Explorer, I

1) pushed Run All,

2) saw an error text in the 
status bar, in the bottom of Visual Studio window.

3) checked - as it instructed - the Output pane for Tests ([Where is the 'tests output pane'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17048391/where-is-the-tests-output-pane?lq=1)). In my case, it complained about exception in discovering tests, not supporting the portable version of NUnit and suggested using a platform specific runner.

4) tried out a solution to solve my error: I uninstalled the NUnit msi, in case it was the portable version not supported.
In VisualStudio, with my project open, I retrieved via NuGet Packgage Manager the NUnit 3.2.1 (April 19, 2016), NUnit Runners 3.2.1 (April 19, 2016), and NUnitTestAdapter 2.0 (April 2,2015). I think retrieving the NUnit Runners was the cure.

Additionally, I also removed from References Microsofts test library which had appeared there during trials. However, I don't believe it had any effect.

Your error description may be different, and may require a different solution.

Comment: Hi EeH, thank u for the help. I removed nunit via nuget, and reinstalled nunit, installed the nunit.runners.net4, it still not work. I did see the nunit runners, is nunit.runners.net4 the one you mentioned?

Comment: I have plain NUnit.Runners.

Comment: Hi EeH, is NUnit.Runners for a console version of NUnit?

Comment: Hi Peter, yes it is.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem in VS2015. I solved it by downgrading NUnit to version 2.6.4. Latest 3.5.0 version appeared to be incompatible with latest NUnitTestAdapter 2.0.0. Seems it refers only to VS 2015, earlier version should be fine.