# ASP.NET MVC 5 error: The type exists in both directories

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2013, asp.net-mvc-5

I am working with Resource files. Previously it was in root directory and it was working in local system only not in build server

So i changed that files to App_ResourceFiles. Now whenever i am running the system its showing error

```
e:\Project\Views\Shared\_Layout.cshtml(20): error CS0433: The type 'Resources.Resources' exists in both 'c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\b16288ea\ad7e7d58\assembly\dl3\84b4e25c\954d49a2_04b6cf01\Project.UI.DLL' and 'c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\b16288ea\ad7e7d58\App_GlobalResources.687j25cv.dll'
```

I restarted the VS2013...deleted the root folder temp files and re-open the solution and clean and rebuild it.
But still it showing the same error again.

any help would be appreciable

Comment: just follow above paths in your system and delete temp files from there also...

Comment: @Exception i did that...but still the same error comingup

Comment: I came across this recently - it's the .NET assembly cache. I think there's a setting that you can use to prevent it being used, etc. Hope this gives you a clue of where to look.

Comment: @Arwin This not cache issue, i guess. It will work in root directories and files if the accessspecifier is global but willnot work in Areas. If the accesspecifier change into Public, it will show errors in root directories and files

Comment: This is what I thought of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8309411/what-is-cache-appdata-local-assembly-dl3

Answer (score 0):

Did you check the Project file?

And you might want to change the namespace.
see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/64wh5743.aspx